# Two questions about the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There's the following:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^p + \left(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}\right)^p + \left(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6}\right)^p+\ldots$$

1.) Is it right using Raabe–Duhamel's test to check if the series converges?

2.) What's the best way to find $n-$th term of the series? numerator and denominator reminds me progression. but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms are $a_n^p$ where $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 4^{n}}$. Check that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{4(n+1)(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{n+1}{n+0.5}=1+\frac{0.5}{n+0.5}$ whereafter, as you say, an application of Raabe's test will (almost) finish the job.

Indeed, $n(\frac{a_n^p}{a_{n+1}^p}-1)\rightarrow \frac{p}{2}$. The only case left is $p=2$.

To resolve that, notice that $\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{a_n^2}=\frac{(n+0.5)^2}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{n^2+n+0.25}{n^2+2n+1}>\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1/(n+1)}{1/n}$ so the sum diverges (along with the harmonic series) for $p=2$.